# How to make Object follow touch movement on screen

Tags: android, actionscript-3, multi-touch, touch-event

Hey guys so I've been trying to solve this for awhile I have looked on many forums and tried to understand what they were trying to convey with the code using ActionScript 3 but i still get nothing. My main goal is to have a character on stage named "mainPlayer" now i want to set up touch events so that when the user drages his finger up down or side to side i want to the mainPlayer to follow the users path  or if the user touches a point on the screen and holds his finger there the mainPlayer will be attracted to the touch and move to the point where the finger is currently at on the screen.

Ive seen lots of stuff with Phase and ID implemented but dont really understand whats going on

so far this is what i have set up:

```
    public class realmEngine extends MovieClip 
{
    //MultiTouch gestures
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

    public var mainPlayer:mcPlayer;


    //PlayerControls
    private var speed:Number = 8.0;
    public var vx:Number = 0;
    public var vy:Number = 0;
    private var friction:Number = 0.85;
    private var maxSpeed:Number = 15;



    public function realmEngine() 
    {
            //Add Player to Stage
        mainPlayer = new mcPlayer();
        stage.addChild(mainPlayer);
        mainPlayer.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 300;
        mainPlayer.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2 );
        //trace("this works");



        //Setup Touch Event listeners
        mainPlayer.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
        stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove);
        stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);

        //Game Loop Event Listener
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);


    }

    private function gameLoop(e:Event):void 
    {
        mainPlayerControls();
    }

    private function mainPlayerControls():void 
    {

    }

    private function onTouchEnd(e:TouchEvent):void 
    {

    }

    private function onTouchMove(e:TouchEvent):void 
    {

    }

    private function onTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent):void 
    {

    }

}
```

I'm not sure what to do inside the onTouch Functions in order for the object that i add to stage by Code to follow the users touch on the screen.

Can anyone lead my in the right direction or give me any advice?  I woudld really appreciate it thanks guys

Comment: Do you want the object to both follow a path drawn by the user and to go to a point touched by the user, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what im trying to accomplish. So whenever you drag your finger across the screen the object will follow it and say you move your finger off the screen the object will stop. Do you know what i should be doing or how to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I happen to know how to do this, I just wasn't sure if I had grasped fully what you wanted to achieve.

**Note** that I won't be taking into account the `speed` and `maxSpeed` variables for moving the player. It's beyond this scope and beyond the scope of the top of my head. A little bit of internet searching will get you far on that subject however!

First of all, in order to make the object follow a path drawn by the user, we need a way to store the path. For this, I suggest a `Vector` with `Point` as its datatype. It's fast and easy to work with when adding and removing elements without having to worry about its length.

We also need a way to tell wether the player sprite should move or not, in other words wether the user is pressing the finger on the screen or not.

```
private var _pathPoints : Vector.<Point>;
private var _isMoving : Boolean = false;
```

Easy-cakes. Now for the fun part!
First, we need to change the scope of the `onTouchBegin` event, from `mainPlayer` to the `stage`. If we don't, the user won't be able to touch an abstract point on the stage and get the player sprite to move there. Simply done with a change to

```
mainPlayer.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
```

Then we take care of when the user moves his or her finger. Nothing fancy going on here.
We're just simply storing the coordinates in our vector and storing the current state of wether the user is pressing the screen or not.

```
private function onTouchBegin ( e:TouchEvent ) : void
{
    _pathPoints.push( new Point( e.stageX, e.stageY ) );
    _isMoving = true;
}

private function onTouchMove ( e:TouchEvent ) : void
{
    _pathPoints.push( new Point( e.stageX, e.stageY ) );
}

private function onTouchEnd ( e:TouchEvent ) : void
{
    // Dirty but quick way of clearing the vector
    _pathPoints.splice(0);
    _isMoving = false;
}
```

Finally, for the even funnier part; the main game loop! Or "Where the Magic Happens".

```
private function mainPlayerControls () : void
{
    // Update player position and forces
    vx *= friction;
    vy *= friction;
    mainPlayer.x += vx;
    mainPlayer.y += vy;

    // Check if the player should be moving to a new point
    if( _isMoving )
    {
        // Get a reference to the current target coordinate
        var target : Point = _pathPoints[0];

        // Check if the player position has reached the current target point
        // We use a bounding box with dimensions equal to max speed to ensure
        // that the player doesn't move across the point, move back towards it
        // and start jojo-ing back and forth
        if(mainPlayer.x >= target.x - maxSpeed && mainPlayer.x <= target.x + maxSpeed &&
           mainPlayer.y >= target.y - maxSpeed && mainPlayer.y <= target.y)
        {
            // The player has reached its target
            //so we remove the first element of the vector
            _pathPoints.shift();
            // and update the target reference
            target = _pathPoints[0];
        }

        // Calculate velocities to the first element of the vector
        vx = mainPlayer.x - target.x;
        vy = mainPlayer.y - target.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. Ill try to implement it in my code when im off work. But it seems simpler than i was thinking haha. Great stuff ill let you know if i run into any problems.

Comment: Okay I am still having some problems. First off you said to change the mainPlayer.addeventlistener to stage.addeventlistener correct? Also no movement of the object seems to be occurring at all. I touch the screen and nothing is happening no traces even. Ill try to figure it out but in the mean timei just wanted to update you and see if there might be some error. Thanks in the mean time.

Comment: Oh yeah i almost forgot the pathPoints.splice(0); requires two arguments so im not exactly sure what the first argument should be seeing as how its not a for loop and i cant just slice the "i" that im used to doing haha

Comment: Sorry just saw your note on it not being able to move the player

Comment: Hm, the player should be moving. Is your class `realmEngine` the main class, or is it instantiated somewhere? I'm thinking if it has an actual reference to the stage. As for the second argument to splice, you can use `Number.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Sorry for not being thorough enough, I'm not very well versed with the TouchEvent. There's a good example of recording touch points on the ASDocs page of TouchEvent. Check the [second example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#includeExamplesSummary).

Comment: Yes its the main class linked to Flash CS6. Also the player is added to the stage through code from a separate class, don't know if that changes anything. Alright will try thanks

Comment: Ok, that's fairly odd then; I'm just curious about it not firing any touch events at all. Like you previously stated you didn't even get any traces. Adding the listener to the stage should fire the callbacks if the stage is touched...

Comment: Yeah i have no idea what could be the problem but ill try to work at it and thanks for the link

Comment: Okay so i commented out thee multitouch.....GESTURE and when i touched the screen it finally responded but game me this error  "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."  on this line " pathPoints.push( new Point(e.stageX, e.stageY));"

Comment: Also just to clarify all 3 of my touchevent listeners should be "stage.addEventListener" correct? not "mainPlayer.addEventListener"

Comment: Ok, regarding the error of null object reference, is either that the `pathPoints` vector hasn't been instantiated or that the `e` reference  isn't being passed to the function. Most likely the latter since you commented out the `GESTURE` part. And yeah, the listeners should be added to the `stage`, otherwise they will only be fired when the user presses on the `mainPlayer` sprite.

Comment: Hmm... Alright ill try to work on it some more and figure this out. My mainPlayer is actually a movie clip and not a sprite. THis wouldnt change anything correct? Arnt movieclip vs sprites basically size difference?

Comment: Ok, hope you'll sort it out! Come back anytime for questions. There are some differences between an MC and a Sprite more than size, such that a movieclip can have a  time line. But in your case it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Did some proper research on the ways AS3 handles touch. It seems that the current method you're using, `GESTURE` is for specific preset movements, such as swiping, double-tapping, rotating etc. What I suggest is remove the `Multitouch.inputMode..GESTURE` and try to figure out what is causing the null object reference error. Try tracing both `pathPoints`, `e` and `e.stageX` separately to figure out which one is the culprit.

Comment: Alright sounds good. I just removed the Gesture. Still gives the error for now. Going to try the Trace and see where that gets me